# IllegalArgumentException: MySQL, Hibernate 4.3+, HikariCP and context.xml

Tags: java, mysql, hikaricp

So here's my set up:

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
<artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
<version>2.4.0-rc4-SNAPSHOT</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Here's where it starts to get sneaky:
pom.xml (Continued)

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
<version>4.3.10.Final</version>
</dependency>

<!-- HikariCP and Hibernate integration -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-hikaricp</artifactId>
<version>4.3.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Need that hibernate-hikaricp jar or you'll get a "missing" ConnectionProvider bug.
In the Hibernate configuration file, lest we forget:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<!-- using HikaricCP for connection pooling deprecated: com.zaxxer.hikari.hibernate.HikariConnectionProvider -->
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider
</property>
     .
     .
     .
```

Now, in my context.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/coolDb" auth="Container" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource"  
factory="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariJNDIFactory"
dataSourceClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
dataSource.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/coolDb:3306?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
dataSource.user="coolUser" 
dataSource.password="coolPasswd" 
connectionTimeout="300000"
cachePrepStmts="true"
prepStmtCacheSize="250" 
prepStmtCacheSqlLimit="2048"
minimumIdle="10" 
maximumPoolSize="20"/>
```

Now, I wish I could report that this is properly configured, but, alas, no such luck.  I'm getting a

> "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: one of either dataSource or
>   dataSourceClassName must be specified..."

Can someone diagnose this noob's bug?

Thanks to @bhdrkn.  He astutely points out that I conflated two approaches.  I solved this problem by taking the Hibernate implementation approach.  I did this, in large part, because the HikariCP documentation encourages this approach ([here](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Hibernate4)).  Even so, I kept the context.xml configuration around to perform JDBC calls when I'm feeling nervous that Hibernate will bungle the complex database call.

context.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/coolDb" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
         driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
         minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000" removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true"
         url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/coolDb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
         username="coolUser"
         password="coolPassword"  maxActive="30" maxIdle="10" maxWait="10000"  initialSize="5" validationQuery= "SELECT 1" validationInterval="30000"
         removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" logAbandoned="true" />
```

Hibernate configuration file:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!-- using HikaricCP for connection pooling -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider
    </property>

    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSourceClassName">com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/coolDb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;autoReconnect=true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.user">coolUser</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.password">coolPassword</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.cachePrepStmts">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize">250</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit">2048</property>

    <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout">300000</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle">10</property> 
    <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize">20</property> 
    <!-- using container-managed JNDI : Not if I'm using HikariCP/Hibernate configuration  
    <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:/comp/env/jdbc/coolDb</property>
    -->
```

Take note: I commented out the old "hibernate.connection.datasource" reference.  It's obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hikaricp 2 different way. [First way](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/JNDI-DataSource-Factory-(Tomcat,-etc.)) is using with a container managed datasource like you do in your context.xml file. [The second way](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/Hibernate4) is defining your connection through hibernate. But you try to do both of them.

If you want to use JNDI data source, you must tell hibernate to use your JNDI data source instead of connection provider information.

Here is an example `hibernate.cfg.xml` which uses JNDI data source.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">java:comp/env/jdbc/coolDb </property>

        <!-- Mapping with model class containing annotations -->
    <mapping class="..."/>
    ....
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Also, if haven't done already you need to specify your resource on your `web.xml`.

```
<resource-env-ref>
    <resource-env-ref-name>jdbc/coolDb</resource-env-ref-name>
    <resource-env-ref-type>javax.sql.DataSource</resource-env-ref-type>
</resource-env-ref>
```

Comment: thank you for describing so well, what probably is so common with open source, you see different approaches described on the internet, so you implement "all" of them.  I'll update my post with the approach that worked, based on your help.

Answer (score 1):

`dataSourceClassName` is not a Driver. You must use a datasource class. For mysql is `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource`.